# Receiving an abnormal amount of unexpected errors when calling PATCH request

Tags: javascript, httprequest, google-apps, patch

I'm not sure what is causing these errors as when I single them out and run them again, they run just fine.  Here is the response log:

```
[, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , [{"message":"An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 1921837509-123724 (662168627)","errorCode":"UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION"}], , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , [{"message":"An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 1142535715-89221 (662168627)","errorCode":"UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION"}], , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , [{"message":"An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 1892498218-91728 (662168627)","errorCode":"UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION"}], [{"message":"An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 665361479-96176 (662168627)","errorCode":"UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION"}], , , , , , , [{"message":"An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 23367811-86680 (662168627)","errorCode":"UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION"}], , , , , , , [{"message":"An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 333477079-125651 (662168627)","errorCode":"UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION"}], , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , [{"message":"An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 1512738979-127867 (662168627)","errorCode":"UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION"}], , , , [{"message":"An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 333477079-125654 (662168627)","errorCode":"UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION"}], , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , [{"message":"An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 2084632066-128628 (662168627)","errorCode":"UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION"}], , , , , , , , , , , , , [{"message":"An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 1055812594-101740 (662168627)","errorCode":"UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION"}], , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , [{"message":"An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 1001679558-110596 (662168627)","errorCode":"UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION"}], [{"message":"An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 1925299595-116430 (662168627)","errorCode":"UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION"}], , , , , , , , , , , , , , , [{"message":"An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 915420034-74113 (662168627)","errorCode":"UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION"}], , , , [{"message":"An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 1892498218-91726 (662168627)","errorCode":"UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION"}], , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , [{"message":"An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 333477079-125649 (662168627)","errorCode":"UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION"}], , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , [{"message":"An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 98981645-70481 (662168627)","errorCode":"UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION"}], , , [{"message":"An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 270290279-133432 (662168627)","errorCode":"UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION"}], , , , , [{"message":"An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 23367811-86677 (662168627)","errorCode":"UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION"}], , , , [{"message":"An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 659221679-101963 (662168627)","errorCode":"UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION"}], , , , , , , , [{"message":"An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 1892498218-91723 (662168627)","errorCode":"UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION"}], , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , [{"message":"An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 2084632066-128626 (662168627)","errorCode":"UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION"}], , , , , , , , , , [{"message":"An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 1001679558-110592 (662168627)","errorCode":"UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION"}], , , , [{"message":"An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 1624144108-127817 (662168627)","errorCode":"UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION"}], , , , , , , , , , , , [{"message":"An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 1705941813-79049 (662168627)","errorCode":"UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION"}], , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , [{"message":"An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 2038031309-82474 (662168627)","errorCode":"UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION"}], , , , , , , , , [{"message":"An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 1892498218-91727 (662168627)","errorCode":"UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION"}], , , , , , , , , , , [{"message":"An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 1001679558-110590 (662168627)","errorCode":"UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION"}], , , , , , , , , [{"message":"An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 1370517856-89833 (662168627)","errorCode":"UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION"}], [{"message":"An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 1804576979-70358 (662168627)","errorCode":"UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION"}], , , , , , [{"message":"An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 23367811-86678 (662168627)","errorCode":"UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION"}], , [{"message":"An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 1043450133-87585 (662168627)","errorCode":"UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION"}], , , , , , , , , , , [{"message":"An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 1804576979-70366 (662168627)","errorCode":"UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION"}], , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , [{"message":"An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 305510904-99594 (662168627)","errorCode":"UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION"}], , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , [{"message":"An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 23367811-86675 (662168627)","errorCode":"UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION"}], , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , [{"message":"An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 560036644-75760 (662168627)","errorCode":"UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION"}], , , , , , , , , , , [{"message":"An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 2104806496-100352 (662168627)","errorCode":"UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION"}], , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , [{"message":"An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 98981645-70480 (662168627)","errorCode":"UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION"}], , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , [{"message":"An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 659221679-101966 (662168627)","errorCode":"UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION"}], , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , [{"message":"An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 1512738979-127862 (662168627)","errorCode":"UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION"}], , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , [{"message":"An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 333477079-125659 (662168627)","errorCode":"UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION"}], ,
```

You can see just how many errors I am getting.

Here is the primary code I am using to PATCH:

```
function upsertPage1(object, idCol) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  var sfService = getSfService();   //this function gets my SF connections *see notes below*
  var userProps = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  var props = userProps.getProperties();
  var name = getSfService().serviceName_;
  var obj = JSON.parse(props['oauth2.' + name]);
  var instanceUrl = obj.instance_url;
  var idCol = colCt1(idCol);   //this function gets a column number from a column letter
  var idField = data[0][idCol];
  var dataJSON = getJSON1(data,idCol);    //this function just gets my sheet data as a JSON
  var requestArr = [];
  for (i=1;i<data.length;i++){
    var id = data[i][idCol];
    var payload = JSON.stringify(dataJSON[i-1]);
    var request = {
      'url': instanceUrl + "/services/data/v42.0/sobjects/" + object +"/" + idField +"/" + id,
      'headers': {Authorization: "Bearer " + sfService.getAccessToken()},
      'contentType': 'application/json',
      'method': 'PATCH',
      'payload': payload,
      'muteHttpExceptions': true
      };    
    requestArr.push(request);
  };
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(requestArr);
}
```

What would cause these errors and how do I correct it?  I need to consistently and accurately update SF and will be doing this as part of a larger code, so I need it to work right the first time.

I don't have this issue using the Salesforce Data Connector add-on, which leads me to believe this can be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like once again I have jumped too soon into the forums.

I found an article somewhere (can't find it again) that suggested rolling back your API version in the HTTP call.  I went from v42 to v38 and that seemed to do the trick.  Hope that helps others!